# regex pattern to match insert sql query

Tags: php, regex

I have some log file which contains **many** rows of similar:

```
[26-Nov-2010 07:33:08] query error: INSERT INTO members (id,name,member_login_key,email,mgroup,posts,joined,ip_address,time_offset,view_sigs,email_pm,view_img,view_avs,restrict_post,view_pop,msg_total,new_msg,coppa_user,language,dst_in_use,allow_admin_mails,hide_email,subs_pkg_chosen,members_l_username,members_l_display_name, item_id, members_display_name)
                                        VALUES(8416961,'abc','3857b123a1a67ce1fc4a39fd7ae47355','test@email.com',1,0,1290756788,'127.0.0.1','',1,1,1,1,
                    0,1,0,0,0,'',0,1,0,0,'abc','abc',
                                        '0', 'abc');|http://www.example.com/|Duplicate entry '8388607' for key 1
[26-Nov-2010 08:33:08] query error: INSERT INTO members (id,name,member_login_key,email,mgroup,posts,joined,ip_address,time_offset,view_sigs,email_pm,view_img,view_avs,restrict_post,view_pop,msg_total,new_msg,coppa_user,language,dst_in_use,allow_admin_mails,hide_email,subs_pkg_chosen,members_l_username,members_l_display_name, item_id, members_display_name)
                                        VALUES(8416962,'abc','3857b123a1a67ce1fc4a39fd7ae47355','test@email.com',1,0,1290756788,'127.0.0.1','',1,1,1,1,
                    0,1,0,0,0,'',0,1,0,0,'abc','abc',
                                        '0', 'abc');|http://www.example.com/|Duplicate entry '8388607' for key 1
```

What I would like to do is to run a regex to match ALL the insert queries only (ignoring the time, url, and the duplicate message.

So it should return:

```
INSERT INTO members (id,name,member_login_key,email,mgroup,posts,joined,ip_address,time_offset,view_sigs,email_pm,view_img,view_avs,restrict_post,view_pop,msg_total,new_msg,coppa_user,language,dst_in_use,allow_admin_mails,hide_email,subs_pkg_chosen,members_l_username,members_l_display_name, item_id, members_display_name)
                                    VALUES(8416961,'abc','3857b123a1a67ce1fc4a39fd7ae47355','test@email.com',1,0,1290756788,'127.0.0.1','',1,1,1,1,
                0,1,0,0,0,'',0,1,0,0,'abc','abc',
                                    '0', 'abc');
INSERT INTO members (id,name,member_login_key,email,mgroup,posts,joined,ip_address,time_offset,view_sigs,email_pm,view_img,view_avs,restrict_post,view_pop,msg_total,new_msg,coppa_user,language,dst_in_use,allow_admin_mails,hide_email,subs_pkg_chosen,members_l_username,members_l_display_name, item_id, members_display_name)
                                    VALUES(8416962,'abc','3857b123a1a67ce1fc4a39fd7ae47355','test@email.com',1,0,1290756788,'127.0.0.1','',1,1,1,1,
                0,1,0,0,0,'',0,1,0,0,'abc','abc',
                                    '0', 'abc');
```

Anyone can assist? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are all the queries 4 lines long? You'd have an easier time just finding lines containing "INSERT" and taking the next 3 lines...

Comment: meagar, yes the queries are 4 lines long :(

Comment: Once you figure out how to get each query (sans other data) onto one line in a file - several answers below will do it (as would sed or awk) - use the *nix commands sort and uniq to get the unique lines.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to extract parts of it, or just match?

Just match is easy, it doesn't require a regex at all, just the substring INSERT INTO.

```
grep 'INSERT INTO' foo.log
```

If you want to extract details, or have a more specific match, please give a little more information.

If you want to have the three following lines, you can do this.

```
grep -A 3 'INSERT INTO' foo.log
```

And if you want to trim some stuff from the start and end (it's pretty ugly, but works on your examples)

```
grep -A 3 'INSERT INTO' foo.log | sed -e 's/^.*INSERT INTO/INSERT INTO/' -e 's/);|.*/);/'
```

Comment: that's possible, but there are multiple lines, so doing a grep like that would just return: INSERT INTO members (id,name,member_login_key,email,mgroup,posts,joined,ip_address,time_offset,view_sigs,email_pm,view_img,view_avs,restrict_post,view_pop,msg_total,new_msg,coppa_user,language,dst_in_use,allow_admin_mails,hide_email,subs_pkg_chosen,members_l_username,members_l_display_name, item_id, members_display_name)

Comment: If the number of lines are constant (e.g. 3 lines each time, as in your example), then it's still straightforward.  I'll amend my answer.

Comment: Hi El, I tested the solution, but that returns the query + the date + url, duplicate message, etc.

Comment: So you want all *unique* records, ignoring the time, url and the duplicate message?

Comment: If the ID is unique for each record, then each insert will still be unique - do you want to ignore that too?

Comment: El, sorry for the confusion. I've modified the question a bit, see if that's clearer now.

Comment: See my last update; this works on your examples, but it's pretty ugly :D

Answer (score 0):

If all the inserts span 4 lines of log file then you could use this regexp:

```
 (.*)(INSERT INTO.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\))(;.*)
```

with this matching replace string:

```
 \2\n
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible, it very much depends if the whole file is identical to that.

This is to get just the INSERTs, if you want the log entries, then the regexp needs to change slightly.

```
$logFile = file_get_contents('inserts.log');

$matches = array();
preg_match_all("/(?P<insert>INSERT .+?;)/s", $logFile, $matches);

foreach ($matches['insert'] as $cQuery) {
    echo $cQuery . "\n";
}
```

See [preg_match_all documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) for further info on this approach.